# Find the object that implements a specific interface

Tags: c#, reflection, log4net-appender

I am writing a log4net Appender and this appender needs the object of the framework of the app initializing log4net. This framework implements a specific interface.
While XmlConfigurator.Configure() is called by this framework, there is no way to pass an object down from Configure() and there is no way to walk up the call stack to get the *this* object at each call.

There is also no way, as far as I can tell, to get a list of all top level objects. (Point of fact, I'm not sure that .NET even has the concept of "top level" objects.) So no way to walk a set of objects finding the one that implements the interface AFAIK.

The best I've come up with is a static MyAppender.SetFramework(frameworkObject) call to be made before XmlConfigurator.Configure(). And I dislike this as it's an ugly hack.

So, any suggestions for a better solution?

**Update:**

At present I've decided to use the following (if there's a better way, please let me know):

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["QCAlgorithm"] = this;
```

Comment: `Assembly.GetTypes` will return all types defined in an assembly. Are you looking for *instances* instead? Does `top level object` mean a singleton? Why do you want that anyway? No other appender needs a reference to the log configuration method or object. Most often, that would be `Program.cs` or a method in `Startup.cs`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes I'm looking for a singleton instance. And yes, this is a very weird situation.

Comment: The static you configure doesn't look like a hack at all. Instead of a static you could have a static factory function you would call so that each time you could even get a fresh instance. But reflection - this is hacky and I'd avoid it here.